# Separating chars and digits in a given set of strings and adding only the digits

Tags: java

here is my code, I want from a given string value only integers to be get calculated.

eg:abc123as34  output:13
here ignoring the strings only digits should get calculated,

Comment: Sorry I can not see your code

Comment: @Keppil I would guess he's summing the digits.

Comment: @Keppil ithink he means 1+ 2+ 3 + +3 + 4 = 13

Comment: first try to extract digit from the strings. Then you can easily sum them.

Comment: @ScaryWombat 

*/ int count=0;
  public void abc(String a)
  {int i1=0;
    String regex="[a-zA-Z]";
    String s1[]=a.split("");
    for(int i=0;i<s1.length;i++)
    {
      if(s1[i].matches(regex)){
        System.out.println();
      }
      else
      {try{
        i1=Integer.parseInt(s1[i]);
      }catch(NumberFormatException ne)
      {System.out.println(ne.getMessage());
        //int i1=Integer.parseInt(s);
        System.out.println("i1...."+i1);
        count=count+i1;
        System.out.println("count...."+count);
        System.out.println(s1[i]);
      }

Comment: @ Thusitha

I tired the same but I am getting number Format exception,when I am trying to convert string into int to sum up them.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it would be to loop through each character in the string, check if it's a digit. If so, add it to some sort of `total` variable. For example:

```
String str = "abc123as34";

int total = 0;
for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
        total += Character.getNumericValue(c);
    }
}   
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
 class Calc

{
   public static void main (String[] args) 
{
 String s="123ab3";
 char[] d=s.toCharArray();
 int total=0;
 for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++)
 {
   try
  {
     total=total+Integer.parseInt(""+d[i]);
     System.out.println(""+total);
  }
  catch(Exception e)
  {
    System.out.print("not no");
  }
}
 System.out.print("total="+total);
   }
 }
```

Ouput  Show :

```
      total=9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the characters in the string one by one and sum each char that is a number:

```
public static int sumInts(String str) {
  int sum = 0;
  for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
      sum += Character.getNumericValue(c);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
```

Comment: r u sure this will give accurate result i don't think so because `(int) c` this will not typecast the char into int .

Comment: What's the value of `(int)'3'`?

Comment: This will not produce the desired result, because if you cast the character '0' to int, it will be 48. It should be `sum += c - '0';`

Comment: Doh! Of course you're right. I've edited my answer (although it's basically equivalent to @Th3Cuber's).